# TF-IDF and text chunks

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf

I am a begginer in NLP and I am using TF-IDF method to apply then a ML model. If I have a dataset like this

```
dataset = ['I have three cars', 'and one motorbike']
```

which is the correct the way (A or B) to apply TF-IDF and why?

Option 1

```
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=100000, ngram_range = (1,2))
Tfidf_vect.fit(dataset)
```

Option 2

```
for d in dataset:
  Tfidf_vect2 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=100000, ngram_range = (1,2))
  Tfidf_vect2.fit(d)
```

Moreover, The Option 2, isn't working, and I can't understand why. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;** The correct way is Option 1(A).

---

The correct way to apply TFIDF Vectorizer is with an text corpus that is:

> An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.

As per [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit), you have to pass, your case an array of texts.

And example from Scikit-learn docs:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.shape)
(4, 9)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question If I have a dataset in this form  dataset = [['document 1], [document 2],...], I could apply tfidf in each document, but how can I do it in the whole dataset. I can use a loop to apply tfidf in each part of the dataset, but then I will have n different X vectors. If there any way to combine them?

Comment: @George You're welcome! Don't forget to accept as answer ;D. Now, about this new dataset, I can think of changing the dataset so that each document is a single text like this: `new_dataset = [' '.join(document) for document in dataset]`. This way you'll end up with the same corpus format that is used in `TfidfVectorizer`.

Comment: thank you so much! One more general question, in case that I have a dataset, training, validation and test sets. Should I fit TF-IDF in the whole dataset and then transform the training, validation and test set or fir the TF-IDF only in the training set?

Comment: Both training and test sets must be vectorized. For reusability I suggest to using pipeline (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) to define your steps.
Basically first split your data into train & test set and then apply the pipeline on first one to train the model and the second one to validate the model.

Comment: @George You should fit only on the training and then transform the others. The idea behind this is that you're going to simulate a real world scenario where you wont have all the data to train on. This way you can better check if your model is able to provide a good generalization.

Comment: @George In the end you would end up with something like this: `fit_transform(train)` then `transform(test)` then `transform(validation)`

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is correct. Fit method requires a list of examples. Check this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit